# Im trying to create flip cards in react app using css ,everything goes fine but there's a borderline that appears outside card . How can i remove same

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[This is image of one of the crads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQiPC.png)

I was not expecting lines outside , a border like structure has come across all the cards and which I don't want

Comment: use the browser DevTools to inspect all the CSS of your card tag and all its parents, find the offending `border**` style

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have passed the border to the card.

Solution:

1. remove the `border` CSS property
2. pass the same value of `border-radius` of the card to the outer border